# ng build throws error: "Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not."

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-build

When trying to build my app with `ng-build`, I get the following error:

> Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.

My main file as specified in `.angular-cli.json` is pretty straightforward:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service'


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [LoginService],
    bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

`ng --version` returns the following:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.0
Node: 6.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.5
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic

@angular/cli: 1.7.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.1
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.1
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.0
@schematics/angular: 0.3.1
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.1
typescript: 2.7.2
webpack-replace: 1.0.0
webpack-vendor-chunk-plugin: 1.0.0
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a clue from David's answer, I tried this and worked for me.

**Step 1**:
Create a new file named **AppModule.ts** inside the same folder as you have main.ts file.

**Step 2**:
Move everything from **main.ts** file to **AppModule.ts** file.

Step 3: 
After the move, **main.ts** file should ONLY have this code:

```
import './polyfills';

import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './AppModule';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**Step 4**:
My **AppModule.ts** file has this code. Your AppModule.ts may have different code based on what you have coded.

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {YOURCustomCode} from './app/YOURCustomCode';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [YOURCustomCode],
  declarations: [YOURCustomCode],
  bootstrap: [YOURCustomCode],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Step 5**:
Run command `ng serve` and it compiles and builds with no error bootstrap module error now.

Comment: This works for me, it has some erros inside the log but I guess it's because of some modules without update. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you. Beginner definitely need this !

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone runs into the same problem, the issue in my case was that I was bootstrapping the app in the same file that contained the module to be bootstrapped (i.e. `AppModule`), whereas `ng build` expects the module to be *imported* into the file where you call `bootstrapModule()`. The relevant code is in the function `resolveEntryModuleFromMain()` in `node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\entry_resolver.js`, which looks for at all of the imports declared in the file where `resolveEntryModuleFromMain()` is called for the module to be bootstrapped. Moving the call to `bootstrapModule()` to another file and importing `AppModule` fixed the issue (and is a better practice anyway).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by importing? I have this exact issue and I can't find a fix for it. Can you expand your answer with some code examples? I've tried to move the `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(SomeModule);` into the module's own `ngOnInit()`, then import the modules inside `app.module.ts`, but I get the same error. Not really sure why I am experiencing it.